# What is the best solution to load the correct gpio mapping for atmega328p in ghidra

Tags: ghidra

All the tutorials I found, use the default **AVR8** default **16 little gcc** configuration when importing the binary. After importing the file with this configuration the gpio register mapping is completely messed up.

What is the best solution to load the correct gpio mapping for **atmega328p** in **ghidra**?

In the scripts managers we can find `CreateAVR8GDTArchiveScrip` but when I run the script ghidra asks for a location for the output and then errors out because it does not find the avr headers

Where does ghidra look for the avr headers when CreateAVR8GDTArchiveScript is run?

Answer (score 1):

Mate, If you're experiencing difficulty when running the script or locating the AVR headers, it might be necessary to verify that you have properly installed the AVR GCC toolchain and that the headers are stored in the appropriate location on your system. You might also have to adjust the script or modify your system's environment variables in order to direct it to the correct location of the headers.